# Add Legend Labels for each Y Value ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, code-behind

I'm making a pie chart from the C# code behind file. Here is the code I am using to give the chart its data:

```
Graph.Series["Data"].Points.AddXY(appointments.LocCode, appointments.OnTime, appointments.Late, appointments.Missed);
```

OnTime, Late, and Missed are all just ints and I really just want a pie chart where the whole is the total of all of them. My problem is, the Legend is displaying the y value of the data point and I need it to show the category it represents (either On Time, Missed, or Late).

I'm already using series labels to display the value and percentage so that's not really an option for this it would have to be in the legend. Also, this chart needs to be dynamically populated based on controls the user chooses on the page so I don't think I can really do anything with the designer or aspx code.

Is there another way I should be binding the data that would be easier to accomplish this? I'm new to ASP.NET/Charts so this whole thing has pretty much been a learning experience.

I've seen this:

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[0].Label = "My Point Label\nLabel Line #2";
```

But I'm not really sure if that works in this case and if it does, how to distinguish which point is in index 0, 1, 2 etc. I did try this code but I received an error "Index out of range", I'm not sure if that was because the test data I used didn't have missed appointments or if it was something with my data binding. When I only used index position 0, it changed my percent and y value label, which kind of defeats the purpose and now that I look at the code, I'm noticing that I'm changing the series label with that and not a legend label.

So, how can I assign legend labels where "On Time" is for appointments.OnTime, "Late" is for appointments.Late and "Missed" is for appointments.Missed? Again, I'm open to changing the data binding I just need this to be the end result. Any suggestions or insight would be greatly appreciated at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some changes and I got the behavior I was looking for. In case others see this in the future and are wondering what I did:

I ended up changing my object data source. Instead of using:

```
public int OnTime { get; set; }
public int Late { get; set; }
public int Missed { get; set; }
public String LocCode { get; set; }
```

I just used:

```
public String LocCode { get; set; }
public String TimeDesc { get; set; }
public int TimeAmt { get; set; }
```

I bound that data to the pie chart with :

```
Graph.DataSource = AData; //where AData is a List of the class I described above
Graph.Series["Data"].XValueMember = "TimeDesc";
Graph.Series["Data"].YValueMembers = "TimeAmt";
```

And my labeling looked like this:

```
Graph.Series["Data"].Label = "#PERCENT\n#VALY";
Graph.Series["Data"].LegendText = "#VALX";
```